# add char to string without help of functions

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, append

for my program I need to add char(char) to string(char *) without using standard library or IO functions.
For example:

```
char *s = "This is GOO";
char c = 'D';

s = append(s, c);
```

and s would produce string "This is GOOD".
Is there some proper way to manipulate arrays in order to achieve this?
Also it would be sufficient to produce string out of number of characters.
I'm pretty sure I can use malloc, not positive though...

```
char * app(char* s, char c){
    char *copy;
    int l = strlen_(s);
    copy = malloc(l+1);
    copy = s;
    copy[l] = c;
    copy[l+1] = '\0';
    return copy;
}
```

can't use strcpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without giving away the answer, since this sounds like classwork, here's what you want to do at a high level:

1. Determine the length of the string, i.e. find the `'\0'` terminator.
2. Allocate a new char array which is one character longer.
3. Copy the old string to the new string.
4. Add the new character on at the end.
5. Make sure there's a `'\0'` terminator at the end of the new string.

(If you're allowed to modify the existing string then you could possibly skip steps 2 and 3. But in your example `char *s = "This is GOO"` has `s` pointing to an unmodifiable string literal, meaning you can't modify it in place and have to work with a copy.)

---

Comments on the code you posted:

```
char * app(char* s, char c) {
    char *copy;
    int l = strlen_(s);
    copy = malloc(l+1);    /* should be +2: +1 for the extra character and +1 for \0 */
    copy = s;              /* arrays must be copied item by item. need a for loop */
    copy[l] = c;
    copy[l+1] = '\0';
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: `s = append(s, c);` implies that `s` is not modified by `append`, unless `append` has a truly wretched specification.

Comment: ' char * app(char* s, char c){
 char *copy;
 int l = strlen_(s);
 copy = malloc(l+1);
 copy = s;
 copy[l] = c;
 copy[l+1] = '\0';
 return copy;
} '

segmentation fault =/

Comment: how to make this format like a code here...?
Anyway, how it is possible to copy old string to the new one without strcpy

Comment: @duskast gave me an answer and you gave me an understanding ,thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *append(char *s, char c)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char *tmp;
    while (s[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    tmp = malloc((i+2) * sizeof(char));
    while (j < i)
    {
        tmp[j] = s[j];
        j++;
    }
    tmp[j++] = c;
    tmp[j] = '\0';
    return tmp;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s = "This is Goo";
    char c = 'D';
    s = append(s, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a) use `strlen` b) `sizeof(char)` is always 1 c) use `memcpy` or `strcpy`

Comment: Oops, sorry, missed the requirement that `strcpy` can't be used. Still, nothing said about `strlen` or `memcpy`.